# RSpec Book example confusion (should_receive)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, bdd

I'm trying to follow the RSpec book right now, but it doesn't seem very clear to me. It has a lib/codebreaker/game.rb file:

```
module Codebreaker
  class Game
    def initialize(output)
      @output = output
    end
    def start
      @output.puts "Welcome to Codebreaker!" 
    end
  end
end
```

I have a spec/codebreaker/game_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module Codebreaker
  describe Game do
    describe "#start" do
      it "sends a welcome message" do
        output = double("output")
        game = Game.new(output)

        output.should_receive(:puts).with("Welcome to Codebreaker!")

        game.start
      end
      it "prompts for the first guess"
    end
  end
end
```

So currently, the "it 'sends a welcome message'" test passes, but I don't understand why.

The game_spec file says that "output" should receive a puts command with "Welcome to Codebreaker!". However, in the game.rb file, we clearly see that output is an ARGUMENT to the intialize method. @outputs, the instance variable and NOT the argument parameter, has puts "Welcome to Codebreaker!" called to it. Why should this test pass when clearly output is not receiving :puts, but @output is?

I would understand if @output.should_receive(:puts).with("Welcome to Codebreaker!") passed, but output is just a parameter passed to initialize. How does RSpec know that output is actually @output or even have access to @output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, in the game.rb file, we clearly see that output is an ARGUMENT to the intialize 
>   method.

Yes, this allows your test to pass in an `output` object designed for testing. It gets saved with this code here:

```
def initialize(output)
  @output = output
end
```

So then,

> `@outputs`, the instance variable and NOT the argument parameter, has puts "Welcome to Codebreaker!" called to it.

It's the same object because `initialize` sets whatever was passed in as an argument to the instance variable `@output`. This instance variable is now available in every instance method.

> Why should this test pass when clearly output is not receiving :puts, but @output is?

Because it's the same object. The test passes the object in, it gets saved to `@output` and then eventually `puts` is called on it.